# Error - Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend-error

Recently, I installed Blog extension from the magento connect store in my magento system. After setting up everything, I added a new blog post (http://jainculture.pavaiyacart.com/blog). This page works fine but as soon as I click on the blog page to read more, it redirects me to another url (http://jainculture.pavaiyacart.com/blog/hello-world.html) but there I get an error page. The error log says the following:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:52:"Front controller reached 100 router match iterations";i:1;s:469:"#0 /home/pavaiyacart/public_html/jainculture/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(180): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')
#1 /home/pavaiyacart/public_html/jainculture/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#2 /home/pavaiyacart/public_html/jainculture/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#3 /home/pavaiyacart/public_html/jainculture/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#4 {main}";s:3:"url";s:22:"/blog/helloworld.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by deleting the cache content from var folder.